# How to add circle around specific points in PCA produced by ggbiplot

Tags: r, pca, ggbiplot

I know how to produce a PCA plot through ggbiplot and this package works well.

But now I want to modify some specific points, such as their color, size and especially **adding circles around some points** but not  cover them by `geom_encircle()` function.

Here is my reproducible example code below:

```
#load required packages
library(ggplot2)
library(devtools)
library(ggbiplot)

#load dataset
data(iris)

#perform principal component analysis
pca = prcomp(iris[ , 1:4], scale=T)

#define classes, generate & view PCA biplot
class = iris$Species
ggbiplot(pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, groups = class, circle = FALSE)+
  geom_point(size = 3,aes(color = class))+
  geom_point(data=iris[iris$Species=="setosa",],pch=21, fill=NA, size=2, colour="black", stroke=2)
```

However, error information appeared:

```
Error in `geom_point()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
i Error occurred in the 5th layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'xvar' not found
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I may know it is caused by data in `geom_point()` which is not consistent to pca.

But I don't know how should I set the data in `geom_point()`

So I hope somebody could give me some advice or solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May want to note that `ggbiplot` is not on CRAN, and can be installed via `install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a hacky way by using `ggplot_build()` to retrieve the data frame that was constructed by `ggbiplot`.

```r
gg0 <- ggplot(data=data,aes(x=data[,1],y=data[,2]))+
  geom_point(size = 3,aes(color = class))
ggb <- ggplot_build(gg0)
```

`ggb$data` is a list with a data frame for each layer of the plot. By poking around a bit we can figure out that the `geom_point` layer is the last (fourth), i.e. `ggb$data[[4]]`.  All we need from this is the `x` and `y` coordinates, which we can combine with the original data set (hoping that row order is preserved, there weren't any incomplete cases discarded, etc.)

```r
my_data <- cbind(iris, ggb$data[[4]][c("x", "y")])
m2 <- subset(my_data, Species == "setosa")
gg0 + 
   geom_encircle(data = m2, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
   geom_point(data=m2, aes(x=x,y=y),
              pch=21, fill=NA, size=2, colour="black", stroke=2)
```

[image]

Comment: A good idea. But a little bit complexed. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's only a few extra lines of code ... and it could be automated a bit. If the answer solves your problem you're encouraged to upvote and/or accept it ...

Comment: That's Ok. I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I get a good idea to produce the plot.

But my method is transfer ggbiplot() to ggplot:
Here is my code

```
#load required packages
library(ggplot2)
library(devtools)
library(ggbiplot)

#load dataset
data(iris)

#perform principal component analysis
pca = prcomp(iris[ , 1:4], scale=T)
class = iris$Species
data<-data.frame(pca$x,class = iris$Species)
#define classes, generate & view PCA biplot

ggplot(data=data,aes(x=data[,1],y=data[,2]))+
  geom_point(size = 3,aes(color = class))+
  geom_point(data=data[data$class %in% c("setosa"),],aes(PC1,PC2),pch=21, fill=NA, size=2, colour="black", stroke=2)
```

It works well **but I don't know how to do it based on the original `ggbiplot ()` function**

This method is good, and it is enough for my request.

But I still want to know who can help me with other similar method.

Thanks in advance.

[image]